# Increment expression for loop

Tags: for-loop, post-increment, decrement, pre-increment, controltransfer

I don't understand, why in for loop incrementation(i++) is executed on second time and ignored on the first iteration? I tried searching this question but can not understand.

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    cout<<"hello, World");
}
```

your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean? Is this C++?

Comment: can you add a tag "c++" and add remove the closing parentheses from your 3rd line? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'i++' is the step size that is 1 here. The counter 'i' allows to move from the current 'position' to the next 'position'. The first current 'position' is 1, you execute the block of instructions (count<<"Hello") then you move to the next 'position' (2) by incrementing the counter 'i'

Answer (score 0):

The **for loop** is like saying:

"Execute everything that is inside the code block (everything inside the parenthesis
{ } ), with the variable "i" that:

starts from 1 ("i=1"), till 10 ("i<=10"), and increment it by 1 at every cycle/loop ("i++").

So, in the first cycle/loop:

"i" is equal to 1, and ***incrementation will happen at the end of the first cycle and the beginning of the second.***

That's why the incrementation is not executed on the first iteration.

PS: You can add a "i++" at the beginning of your code block if you want that.

I hope it's clear.